# Master Git repository for bunch of "Projects"

Tags: c#, git, repository, git-submodules, libgit2sharp

First of all, thanks very much for having me in this community! :D

Secondly, let's go straight to the issue!

Today, I'm the unique responsible for a bunch of projects, and after some time, we decided to delegate these projects to other employees, because many times the code modification isn't needed to be made by me, the technician can do it easily. For today, each code modification is delegated to me, so in that way, its easy to control the Projects.

Then if we start working with more people, it will be more difficult to control these projects. Then I wondered (haha) that why don't use Git as our project controller?

I started deveolping an application that uses LibGit2Sharp (which is great!) for controlling the projects, but then I realized that I'll have to create tons of projects for controlling each one. And each projects is more like a configuration file, not development. It would be great if all these projects could be controlled in the same project (as a submodule, for example). I started looking for what submodules gives me and I don't think is the same as I need.

The project structure would be like this:

```
/Master Project 
   /.git
   /MySoftwareV1
       /Customer1
          /.git
          ConfigFile1.cfg
          ConfigFile2.cfg
          ConfigFile3.cfg
       /Customer2
          ...
       /Customer3
          ...
       /Customer4
          ...
   /MySoftwareV2
       /Customer5
          /.git
          ConfigFile1.cfg
          ConfigFile2.cfg
          ConfigFile3.cfg
       /Customer6
          ...
       /Customer7
          ...
       /Customer8
          ...
```

Is it possible to implement? 
In this case, my application will control the submodules for the users check-out/in.

If you guys need more information, please don't hesitate to tell me!

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep it simple, use a single Git repository without fancy stuff like submodules and instead mirror the project structure as a file folder hierarchy.

If you want to have more control on what the technicians do, you could let each one of them work on their own branch, so they can't damage someone else's work. It would be your (or your LibGit2Sharp-based application's) task to review their changes and to merge them to the master branch.

Since Git keeps track of the whole change history, you can always undo unwanted changes.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for replying! And yes, the purpose is exactly for me to review the techs changes, but i'm affraid of the project getting giant...

Comment: Then ask for ask for salary increment! :-)